# How does Spartacus lazy-load CSS styles?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

We are working with ASM, and we noticed that Spartacus lazy-loads ASM styles. We could not find any documentation on how this is done in Spartacus.

This would be useful for us, since we have our custom CSS code for ASM, and we would like to lazy-load it as well (and possibly to do the same in other places of the project, if possible).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Spartacus doesn't support lazy loading css files, and it's not even in the roadmap for version 5.0.